# How can I search through an array that returns both the position of the value and the number of comparisons?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a function that searches an array for a given value and returns its position if found. However, I also want it to update the number of comparisons it took to search through the entire array. But it is not working and crashes once it exits the function and calls for the parameter.

```
int linSearch(int arr[], int size, int target, int* numComparisons) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count++;
        if (arr[i] == target) {
            numComparisons = count;
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -999;
}
```

I am calling the function with this

```
linSearch(userArray, userEntries, valSearch, *numLinSearch)
```

and the variable numLinSearch is this

```
int *numLinSearch = 0;
```

When i try to print out something like printf("%d", numLinSearch); the program crashes. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numComparisons = count;
```

You are changing the *value* of the pointer, not value of the pointed object. It should be rather:

```
*numComparisons = count;
```

`numComparisons` has to contain the address of a variable so that the function can process its data. Therefore you should call `linSearch` like this:

```
int numComparisons = 0; /* for example */
linSearch(userArray, userEntries, valSearch, &numLinSearch)
```

rather than:

```
int *numComparisons = 0; /* numComparisons is a null pointer */
```

Comment: Thanks! Since the function and its parameter was given, I thought I had to use a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize

```
   int * numLinSearch = 0
```

you set numLinSearch to NULL and when you attempt to dereference it in the method it crashes

initialize it as

```
    int * numLinSearch = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

or alternatively, (not recommended if you want to save this pointer out of scope)

```
    int temp = 0;
    int * numLinSearch = &temp;
```

Comment: Should I initialize it to 1 instead of 0?

Comment: You could also make numLinSearch an `int` instead of an `int *` and then pass in `&numLinSearch` instead of `numLinSearch`

Answer (score 0):

It crashes not when you call `printf`, but when  you call `linSearch`.
The correct call should look like this:

```
linSearch(userArray, userEntries, valSearch, &numLinSearch);
```

to pass `numLinSearch` by reference